# C#. Get all cell in a row by row index in a data grid

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the row index of a table. I need to get the value of each cell in the row and add it to a list. I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: What's the context? ASP.NET?  WPF?  Winforms?

Comment: Windows Forms. Sorry.

Comment: *"I can't seem to get it right"* It'll be a lot easier for us to help if you show us what you've tried already. Otherwise we don't know what part you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through DataGridView rows and add specific index value to a list,

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<string> items = new List<string>();
   foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
     if (null != item && null != item.Cells[0].Value)
     {
       items.Add(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
     }                
   }
}
```